# How to show / debug PEAR::DB errors in webpage?

Tags: php, pear

I am connecting to MySQL database on my webpage and have this copy-pasted code for errors:

```
if(DB::isError($db)) die($db->getMessage());
```

I have the connection code in an outside file called connection.inc that I include at the beginning of my page before the DOCTYPE and html tags.

For debugging purposes, how can I print the database errors on my webpage?

I thought I could do something like this:

```
echo 'Could not connect to database. The error was:' . $db->getMessage();
```

but this returns: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB_mysql::getMessage()

The connection.inc looks like this:

```
require_once("DB.php");
$dsn="mysql://mannerv_bonus:blahblah@localhost/mannerv_bonus";
$db = DB::connect($dsn);
if(DB::isError($db)) die($db->getMessage());
else $db->query("SET NAMES 'latin1'");
```

I tried this:

```
if(DB::isError($db)) {
echo 'There was an error';
echo $db->getMessage();
}
```

I can change the password and do whatever but it seems that the isError is never true. I thought that if the password is wrong, this would be an error.

Comment: Any solution for this? I'm having the same issue on a legacy system.

Answer (score 0):

It fails because it isn't a PEAR Error object. (Which means the db connect was successful)

```
if (PEAR::isError($db)) {
    echo $db->getMessage();
}
```

But the `die` at the top (in your `connection.inc`) will stop the script execution immediately and any code below it will never be run.

Comment: This is what puzzles me; I still get the same error even if I change my password to some blah blah or otherwise mess with my database connection, ie. it seems that I am never able to print out any errors even though there for sure are some.

Comment: Does the script `die` when you change the password? How does your `connection.inc` look like?

Comment: The connection.inc looks like this:

    require_once("DB.php");
    $dsn="mysql://mannerv_bonus:blahblah@localhost/mannerv_bonus";
    $db = DB::connect($dsn);
    if(DB::isError($db)) die($db->getMessage());
    else $db->query("SET NAMES 'latin1'");

I tried this:

    if(DB::isError($db)) {
    echo 'There was an error';
    echo $db->getMessage();
    }

I can change the password and do whatever but it seems that the isError is never true. I thought that if the password is wrong, this would be an error.

Comment: What if you change the database or host name?

Comment: No reaction. Seems that I can put whatever and there are never any errors.

Comment: That's odd. I've no idea how to help you further. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The connection.inc looks like this:

```
require_once("DB.php");
$dsn="mysql://mannerv_bonus:blahblah@localhost/mannerv_bonus";
$db = DB::connect($dsn);
if(DB::isError($db)) die($db->getMessage());
else $db->query("SET NAMES 'latin1'");
```

I tried this:

```
if(DB::isError($db)) {
echo 'There was an error';
echo $db->getMessage();
}
```

I can change the password and do whatever but it seems that the isError is never true. I thought that if the password is wrong, this would be an error.